# Add remote name to PowerShell prompt with posh-git

Tags: git, powershell, github, terminal, prompt

I'm using posh-git to add git information to my PowerShell prompt. I want to have my prompt include the remote repository name like [the examples](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/wiki/Customizing-Your-PowerShell-Prompt) but can't find a way to do so.

Below is my profile with my custom prompt:

```
function prompt {
    $origLastExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE

    $curPath = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path
    if ($curPath.ToLower().StartsWith($Home.ToLower())) {
        $curPath = "~" + $curPath.SubString($Home.Length)
    }

    Write-Host "$env:UserName" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host "@" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "$(hostname)" -NoNewline
    Write-VcsStatus
    Write-Host "`n$curPath" -NoNewline

    $LASTEXITCODE = $origLastExitCode

    " $('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}

Import-Module posh-git

$global:GitPromptSettings.BeforeText = " ("
$global:GitPromptSettings.AfterText = ")"
$global:GitPromptSettings.EnableWindowTitle = "posh-git ~"
$global:GitPromptSettings.EnableStashStatus = $true
$global:GitPromptSettings.BeforeStashText = " {"
$global:GitPromptSettings.AfterStashText = "}"
$global:GitPromptSettings.BeforeStashForegroundColor = "Yellow"
$global:GitPromptSettings.AfterStashForegroundColor = "Yellow"
$global:GitPromptSettings.BranchUntrackedSymbol = "::"
$global:GitPromptSettings.BranchGoneStatusSymbol = "~~"
$global:GitPromptSettings.BranchIdenticalStatusToSymbol = "=="
$global:GitPromptSettings.BranchAheadStatusSymbol = "<<"
$global:GitPromptSettings.BranchBehindStatusSymbol = ">>"
$global:GitPromptSettings.BranchBehindAndAheadStatusSymbol = "><"
```

This is the result:

```
spike@Jacob-Laptop (master == +0 ~1 -0 !)
~\Documents\Projects\GUI Utilities\batch-media-file-converter >
```

**This is what I want:**

```
spike@Jacob-Laptop [spikespaz/batch-media-file-converter] (master == +0 ~1 -0 !)
~\Documents\Projects\GUI Utilities\batch-media-file-converter >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the following code:

```
$remoteName = (git remote get-url origin).Split("/")

Write-Host $remoteName[-2] -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "/" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $remoteName[-1] -NoNewline
Write-Host "]" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

It has to only be executed if the current directory is a git directory. Check that with `Test-Path ".git"`.

The command `git remote get-url origin` returns the remote URL such as `https://github.com/spikespaz/batch-media-file-converter`. This can be split at `/` characters, where the last two indices are `(user, repo)`.

I also got it working by extracting the user and repository name with regex (`([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$`), but I presume splitting is faster.

The only problem I see with this is that the URL returned from the command may have `.git` or something at the end. It could also be an SSH address. I don't use either of those types of git addresses, so if anyone finds that this breaks let me know.

```
$remoteName = [regex]::match((git remote get-url origin), "([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$").Groups

Write-Host $remoteName[1] -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "/" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $remoteName[2] -NoNewline
Write-Host "]" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

<s>This is the full code:</s> **See edit.**

```
function Prompt() {
    <...>
}

Import-Module posh-git
```

I would still like to know how it was done in the example, and I'm sure it would be cleaner however that was done, <s>so I won't accept this as an answer but rather leave it here as a workaround.</s> **Edit 2:** I am accepting this as an answer for now because I had expected someone else to respond, but nobody did. It is the only solution I've found this-far.

**Edit:** If you like this profile configuration, I've made a gist that I will update whenever I change it. https://git.io/vAqYP